# Docker build: /make: Permission denied

Tags: docker, makefile, erlang

I'm having problems trying to build an image with erlang 26 compiled from source, when I run `docker build .` I get

```bash
 => ERROR [ 7/14] RUN /home/erl/otp_src_26.0.2/make                                                                                                                       0.3s
------
 > [ 7/14] RUN /home/erl/otp_src_26.0.2/make:
#0 0.244 /bin/sh: 1: /home/erl/otp_src_26.0.2/make: Permission denied
------
Dockerfile:53
--------------------
  51 |     
  52 |     
  53 | >>> RUN /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/make 
  54 |     
  55 |     RUN /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/make install && \
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/make" did not complete successfully: exit code: 126
```

I've tried setting root user with `USER root`, using `make 4.2` and `chmod 777` the entire folder but nothing changes. I can follow the same steps on my local machine and they work.

Before this i was using `https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb` but they doesn't provide the last versions.

I know i can use the official image, but I like to do it this way first

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV ERLANG_VERSION 26.0.2
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        git \
        gnupg \
        inotify-tools \
        make \
        gcc \
        libssl-dev \
        libncurses-dev \
        wget && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Erlang
RUN wget -P /home/erl https://github.com/erlang/otp/releases/download/OTP-${ERLANG_VERSION}/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}.tar.gz -C /home/erl

RUN /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/configure

RUN /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/make 

RUN /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/make install && \
    rm -r /home/erl

WORKDIR /app
```

Comment: Can you use the Docker Hub [`erlang`](https://hub.docker.com/_/erlang) (or possibly [`elixir`](https://hub.docker.com/_/elixir)) image, or install the Ubuntu [`erlang`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/erlang) package, instead of trying to rebuild them from scratch?

Comment: yep, I could use `1.15.4-erlang-26.0.2-ubuntu-jammy-20230126` or something similar, but the real container is a little more complicated also I was curious about getting access denied while being root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/make` is a directory and so you get the cryptic message 'Permission denied' when you try to run it.

The `make` executable isn't located in the Erlang directory. It's installed in `/usr/bin`. Make assumes that you're running it from the directory where your project is located.

Instead of

```
RUN /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/configure

RUN /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/make 

RUN /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION}/make install && \
    rm -r /home/erl
```

you can `cd` into the directory and run the commands you need. Like this

```
RUN cd /home/erl/otp_src_${ERLANG_VERSION} && \ 
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    cd / && \
    rm -r /home/erl
```

Comment: omg it is a directory, thank you!